# Use ListBox within Focus Scope

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, focus, user-experience

Short story: A ListBox inside a focus scope doesn't allow an item to be selected.

Long story:

I am trying to make a context-sensitive widget for data entry. I have the main panel with several fields. Below that, I have a panel with `FocusManager.FocusScope="True"`. This panel will be filled with the relevant widget for the field which currently has focus. For example, selecting a date field would show a calendar at the bottom of the screen.

I have several controls that the require the user to select one of many values from a list. I put a ListBox into the focus scope, but I can't select any items. When something is selected (programmatically) and you click on the ListBox, it deselects everything.

I tested a few events, and it isn't picking up MouseDown events, but it is picking up MouseMove events. It fires GotFocus whenever I click on an item, but it never fires LostFocus. I'm not sure what this means, but I hope it can be helpful to someone who is reading this.

Here is the code that I am using to display the context-sensitive widget. I have the following XAML in my Window:

```
<Grid x:Name="EntryWidget" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ListBox x:Key="List" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
    </Grid.Resources>
</Grid>
```

I use the Window.GotFocus routed event to update the widget to the appropriate control, like so:

```
private void Window_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement focus = (FrameworkElement)FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);
    EntryWidget.Children.Clear(); // Could this be the culprit?
    object tag = focus.Tag;
    if (tag != null)
    {
        if (EntryWidget.Resources.Contains(tag))
        {
            EntryWidget.Children.Add(EntryWidget.Resources[tag] as UIElement);
        }
    }
}
```

So:

1. Is there a way to get the ListBox to work within a focus scope?
2. Or is there another list control that works better inside a focus scope?
3. Or am I taking the wrong approach by using focus scopes? My requirements: The user must be able to select an item from a scrollable list, which will enter the value into the current field. The current field should not lose focus.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, but have you looked at linking collection views, this is when one item of a collection is selected the other collection gets automatically updated. Here is a link from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.aspx

Comment: I only have one ListBox. When an item is selected, it should update the TextBox that has focus. But I can't select any items.

Comment: how about this, if you have a dp of type textbox that gets updated by a textbox when it gets focus, setting the dp equal to itself. Then when you click on a list, you update the dp which has the textbox of the last element that had the focus, i know it is a workaround but it should work.

Comment: @mihajlv: If I did go that route, I would just use a private field. That would be a last resort.

Answer (score 2):

My answer would be to *not use focus scope* for this.

You're kindof defeating the purpose of focus.  What if someone can't use the mouse and wants to use the keyboard instead?

why not just have selection in the list then set focus back to the original control, instead of doing all this extra work with focus scopes?

Comment: Good thought. This application is designed for a tablet PC, therefore keyboard support is not a high priority. But aren't focus scopes designed for a situation like this? It would be a lot of work to implement your own focus system, not?

Comment: but if it is for a tablet system, with touch only, what is focus needed for at all?  If you're not using it for *keyboard focus*, then i'm not sure what youre using it for.

Comment: We may let the user eventually type directly. If I wouldn't use focus to keep track of the current field, what would I use then? Focus cues, like a highlighted TextBox, are helpful, and it would be counter-intuitive to have the focus showing on some other control than the current field. And please don't judge me for trying to do data entry on a tablet. :) :(

Comment: But, as the docs say: `A focus scope is a container element that keeps track of the FocusManager.FocusedElement within the its scope.`  you appear to be trying to use it, combined with a focus listener to *prevent* focus from going somewhere.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use an editable combobox, or the listbox directly instead of a textbox AND a contextually changing listbox, or something like the popup list view things that iphone and windows phone use?

Comment: What do you mean by a 'focus listener' and 'trying to prevent focus'? I am using focus scopes with the same idea as a menu strip: To keep the 'focus' on the current field on the form.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6564/discussion-between-john-gardner-and-kendfrey)

Answer (score 1):

When you click the ListBox or an item it contains, you are setting the keyboard focus of your application to the ListBox. This happens regardless of focus scopes you've defined.

It is possible to define a focus scope for the *upper* panel (the one containing the fields), and have the ListBox's `SelectionChanged` set focus to the upper panel, which will actually set focus to the item that was focused in that panel before any ListBox item was clicked.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="upperPanel" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True" GotFocus="upperPanel_GotFocus">
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"></TextBox>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBoxItem>First</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Second</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Third</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox x:Name="ListBox2" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>6</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>

private IInputElement focusedElement = null;

private void upperPanel_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    focusedElement = e.Source as IInputElement;
}

private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTextBoxValue((e.AddedItems[0] as ListBoxItem).Content.ToString());
}

private void UpdateTextBoxValue(string text)
{
    TextBox focusedTextBox = focusedElement as TextBox;
    if (focusedTextBox != null)
    {
        focusedTextBox.Text = text;
    }

    upperPanel.Focus();
}
```

The currently active control in the `upperPanel` scope is kept up-to-date by the `GotFocus` event handler, and the `UpdateTextBoxValue` method is in charge of setting the text on the active `TextBox` control and setting the focus back to it.

I'm assuming you are familiar with the terms I was using (keyboard focus/logical focus); if not, you can have a look at [Focus Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) or you can just ask.

Comment: Hmm, sounds hackish. I have several controls besides the ListBox that may be displayed for other fields. If I have to do that GetFocusedElement for every control I want to display, uh, is there a better way? You mentioned that it is setting the keyboard focus to the ListBox. If that is the case, why does pressing a key type into the field in the main focus scope? The ListBox doesn't seem to have the keyboard focus.

Comment: @kendfrey I've edited my answer. If you're referring to my example, pressing a key types text in the textbox because I'm setting the keyboard focus back to it from code.

Comment: Doesn't your `focusedElement` field defeat the purpose of a focus scope? And I am not referring to your code. My code doesn't let me (keyboard) focus on the ListBox. I will post the code that I think could be relevant.

Comment: The updated example in fact doesn't make use of a focus scope, but it does solve your problem. The definition of `FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"` in the example allows you to set focus to other controls/scopes, but when you select the grid, it will remember the last focused item inside it and set the focus back to it. That is the meaning and purpose of focus scopes, and I think you may have a different idea of what focus scopes are meant to achieve. If you still think there's something wrong with this example, please let me know.

Comment: Menus are inside separate focus scopes so the main focus scope remembers which is the active control. How is my situation different?